# Scroll CoordinatorLayout using ScrollBar instead of RecyclerView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

Someone can help me to scroll CoordinatorLayout using `ScrollView` instead of 
`RecyclerView`?

> it's not working without RecyclerView.
>
> [See This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYqek.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want to replace the `RecyclerView` with a `ScrollView`, use a `NestedScrollView` instead.

Comment: thanks, very useful :)